# Angular selector issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, select

I have a problem with angular. I'm new at using it.

I have the next json

```
[
   {
      "name":"43",
      "values":{
         "audio":"Audio Only",
         "low":"Low Bandwidth",
         "medium":"Medium Bandwidth",
         "high":"High Bandwidth",
         "mbr2":"2 MBR",
         "mbr3":"3 MBR"
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"169",
      "values":{
         "low":"Low Bandwidth",
         "medium":"Medium Bandwidth",
         "high":"High Bandwidth",
         "hd":"HD Bandwidth",
         "mbr2":"2 MBR",
         "mbr3":"3 MBR"
      }
   }
]
```

This represents qualities I have to encode something. I want to create this selector:

```
4:3 
 - Audio Only
 - Low Bandwidth
16:9
 - Audio Only
 - Low Bandwdith
```

In order to do it I need:

This is what I've so far:

```
<select id="quality" name="quality" data-disable_search=true ng-model="qualities" ng-options="item.name as labelgroup for item in qualities" >
    <optgroup label="{{labelgroup}}" ng-model="item.values" ng-options="value for (value, k) in item.values">
        <option value="{{k}}">{{value}}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

But it is not working... ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to note here is that you need to have the data source and the model to be two separate fields in your controller. That basically means in my mock controller I ended up with:

```
// jsonString is a sample string - more about this in a moment
$scope.qualities = JSON.parse(jsonString);
$scope.selectedQuality = $scope.qualities[0];
```

Now, this in mind, in order to make this work really easily you are going to want to change your JSON structure slightly. I modified it to being an array where each object is the following format:

```
 {
   "category":"16:9",
   "type":"mbr2",
   "display": "2 MBR"
 },
```

Basically, assuming you can do this, getting the selection box you want is as simple as the following html:

```
<select id="quality" ng-model="selectedQuality" name="quality"
        ng-options="item.display group by item.category for item in qualities">
</select>
```

The main idea here is rather than trying to group in the back end - you can pass all the objects through to the front end and allow angular to do the grouping for you. This very much simplifies your front end and it shouldn't be terribly difficult to create these objects on the server.

**See this all working in a plunker here:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pKKwjFZ2tz42a0X87VQD?p=preview

---

**Edit -- make the "original" JSON work...**

If you a really tied to the original JSON where sorting is done on the server, you are going to have to change it slightly so that the key and value pairs make more sense, but you can use ng-repeat and manually put together the select list and headings yourself. See that working in a [revised plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J7boqwCuzNIskUWT7iVP?p=preview). Note that I wouldn't recommend this as much because you are effectively loosing *some* of the power of the angular two way html bindings.